# API Google Java Tomcat 7

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, rest, tomcat

To my college work I've to implement Google API in my tomcat servlets project. Tomcat doesn't execute when I'm using a token of the library `import org.scribe.model.*`. It doesn't give any error in the code, just tomcat doesn't execute "Server Tomcat 7.0 Server at localhost failed to start".
My token variable is EMPTY_TOKEN;

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest requestHttp, HttpServletResponse responseHttp) throws ServletException, IOException {

      OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                                    .provider(GoogleApi.class)
                                    .apiKey("CLIENT ID")
                                    .apiSecret("CLIENT SECRET")
                                    .callback(CALLBACK_URL)
                                    .scope(SCOPE)
                                    .build();


      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("=== " + NETWORK_NAME + "'s OAuth Workflow ===");
      System.out.println();

      System.out.println("Fetching the Authorization URL...");
      String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);
      System.out.println("Got the Authorization URL!");
```

The imports are:

```
import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.*;
```

I know that the problem is the Token, but I don't understand why.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to put a try catch statement around the doGet to see if there is an exception that you are not properly catching and printing.

also this kind of looks dubious:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Trying to figure out why you need the system input on a servlet call.
Are you trying to type commands on a console on the server side?

Comment: I was using. The initialization of Scanner was there for mistake. Sorry. Gives me the same, the tomcat stops and the app don't do nothing.

Comment: what happens when you comment out your code, does the server start? I can't see how a string variable prevents tomcat from starting up. The function isn't even being executed yet for one.